# How display object in angular?

Tags: json, angular, object

when I try to display a specific object from the backend, it displays it as [object Object],
Angular code:

```
InstanceId : any ;
     ngOnInit() {

    this.services.getInstanceId().subscribe(data =>{
      console.log("datajson2 is : " + JSON.stringify(data));

      this.InstanceId = data;
      console.log("InstanceId is : " + InstanceId);
    
    } 
  }
```

json object is :

```
datajson2 is : {"case-id":"13","case-description":"vacation_Approval","case-owner":null,"case-status":1,"case-definition-id":"get_started.vacation_Approval","container-id":"get_started_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT","case-started-at":1609848097820,"case-completed-at":null,"case-completion-msg":"","case-sla-compliance":0,"case-sla-due-date":null,"case-file":null,"case-milestones":null,"case-stages":null,"case-roles":null}
```

error variable that should contains datajson2 :

```
InstanceId is : [object Object]
```

Comment: Use comma instead of plus: `console.log("InstanceId is: ", InstanceId)`

Comment: thank you Michael , its work but when I try to display it in Template as <td>{{ Instance Id.case-id}}</td> its gives me 'Nan'

Comment: The hyphen must be causing the issue. Use bracket notation to access the property instead: `<td>{{ Instance Id["case-id"]}}</td>`

Comment: thank you very much, Michael, could you please replay to my question as the answer not comment to mark it for others ?

Comment: I've posted an answer.

Comment: The question was how to display objects in angular and I posted my answer accordingly. It's sad that the ops accepted her answer to the second question.

Comment: To read more about the json pipe visit Angular official pages https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Concatenate string and object in controller**

You need to use comma instead of plus to log the object in the controller.

```js
console.log("InstanceId is: ", InstanceId)
```

instead of

```js
console.log("InstanceId is: " + InstanceId)
```

**2. Render object property in the template**

The hyphen in the property must obfuscate for the template rendered to access it. You could use bracket notation instead of dot notation here.

```html
<td>{{ Instance Id["case-id"]}}</td>
```

instead of

```html
<td>{{ Instance Id.case-id}}</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your template use the pre tag and json pipe,

```js
<pre> {{ InstanceId | json }} </pre>
```

Comment: thanks, it works but when  I try to display it in Template as <td>{{ Instance Id.case-id}}</td> its gives me 'Nan'

Comment: it means you already receive  Instance Id.case-id as NAN

Answer (score 0):

this.instanceId = JSON.parse(data); should do the trick